# Nontrivial signed measure on Lebesgue measurable sets being trivial on Borel sets

Tags: set-theory, real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

Let $\mathfrak{L}(\mathbb{R})$ be the collection of Lebesgue measurable sets and $\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})$ be the Borel sets.

**Question:** Is there a nontrivial **signed** measure on $\mathfrak{L}(\mathbb{R})$ that is trivial on $\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})$?

Obviously, any **positive** measure that is trivial on $\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is also trivial on $\mathfrak{L}(\mathbb{R})$, since any Lebesgue measurable set is a subset of a Borel set.

For the signed case, I have tried doing Jordan decomposition but it doesn't seem work. It is hard (if ever possible) to show $(\mu|_{\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})})^+ = \mu^+|_{\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})}$ and $(\mu|_{\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})})^- = \mu^-|_{\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})}$.

In fact, If I can deal this problem by decomposition, there must be something special about Borel sets, since the above equalities do not hold in general. Let $\mathfrak{C} = \{\varnothing,\{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\}\}$, $\mathfrak{D} = \{\varnothing, \{0,1\}\}$. The signed measure $\lambda$ on $\mathfrak{C}$ is defined that $\lambda(\{0\})=1$ and $\lambda(\{1\})=-1$. Then $\lambda|_\mathfrak{D}$ is trivial and the equalities fail.

**Background**: I am trying to prove (or disprove) that if $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are signed measures on $\mathfrak{L}(\mathbb{R})$, then $\mu|_{\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})} = \lambda|_{\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})}$ implies $\mu = \lambda$.

Comment: Use the Hahn decomposition instead.

Comment: If $(H^+,H^-)$ is a Hahn decompostion of $\mu$. Do you mean I should apply the positive case to $\mu(E\cap H^+)$ and $\mu(E\cap H^-)$?

Comment: So every Borel subset of $H^+$ or $H^-$ is null... but I don't see how that helps.  @MichaelGreinecker can you give another hint?

Comment: I guess one note is the following.  Suppose a nontrivial measure $\mu$ exists, so $\mu(H^+) > 0$.  We can write $H^+ = B^+ \cup N^+$ where $B^+$ is Borel and $N^+$ is null.  Since $\mu(B^+) = 0$ by assumption, $\mu(N^+) > 0$.  In particular, $N^+$ is not Borel and necessarily uncountable.  But every subset of $N^+$ is Lebesgue measurable, so $\mu|_{N^+}$ is a nontrivial countably additive positive measure on $2^{N^+}$.  I think this makes $|N^+|$ a real-valued measurable cardinal, or at least implies the existence of one, and this is unprovable in ZFC.

Comment: Does @NateEldredge's comment work in reverse?  If there is a real-valued measurable cardinal, can we use it to construct an example as in the OP?

Comment: @NateEldredge I was overly optimistic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, promoting my answer to a comment, this is unprovable in ZFC (assuming ZFC is consistent).  I claim that such a signed measure $\nu$ exists only if there exists a  nontrivial, atomless, countably additive probability measure $\mu$ on the discrete $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$ (or equivalently $[0,1]$).  As I understand it, the latter is equivalent to the existence of a real-valued measurable cardinal of size at most $\mathfrak{c}$, which is independent of ZFC.

Suppose such $\nu$ exists.  Consider its Hahn decomposition $\mathbb{R} = H^+ \cup H^-$.  Since $H^+ \in \mathfrak{L}(\mathbb{R})$, it can be written $H^+ = B^+ \cup N^+$ where $B^+$ is Borel and $N^+$ is Lebesgue-null.  By assumption $\nu(B^+) = 0$ so we must have $\nu(N^+) > 0$, and $\nu$ is positive on $N^+$.  Now every subset of $N^+$ is Lebesgue measurable, so $\nu$ is defined for every such subset.   Thus define $\mu(A) = \nu(A \cap N^+)$ for any subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}$.  This is a nontrivial, countably additive, finite, positive measure on $2^{\mathbb{R}}$, which we may rescale to a probability measure.  And since singletons are Borel, and therefore have $\nu$-measure zero, $\mu$ is atomless.

Gerald's answer, with Michael's comments, seems to be establishing the converse, that the existence of a real-valued measurable cardinal implies the existence of a desired $\nu$.  Combining these would show that the original statement is independent of ZFC.

Comment: Thanks. I see it is impossible to show the existence of such measure in ZFC if ZFC is consistent. However, why is the signed measure $\nu$ constructed in the converse nontrivial on Lebesgue measurable sets?

Comment: @Zhang: Responded on the other answer.

Comment: Thank you. I have added a new comment below your response.

Answer (score 3):

*a converse of Nate Eldridge's comment*
**not a proof, too long for a comment**

Suppose there is a real-valued measurable cardinal.  We want to show
there is a measure as requested.

There is a probability measure $\mu : \mathfrak P([0,1]) \to [0,1]$.
We may assume $\mu([0,t]) = t$ for $0 \le t \le 1$.

Using AC of course, can we show the existence of a set $X \subseteq [0,1]$
with
$$
\mu(X \cap [0,t]) = t/2\quad \text{for all }t \in [0,1]\quad?
\tag1
$$
We can deduce from this:
$$
\mu\big(X \cap B\big) = \frac{1}{2}\lambda\big(B\cap[0,1]\big)
\quad\text{for all Borel sets }B.
\tag2$$
Then the signed measure we want will be
$$
\nu(E) = \mu\big(X \cap E\big) - \mu\big((\,[0,1]\setminus X)\cap E\big)
$$
From $(2)$ we can prove that $\nu(B) = 0$ for all Borel sets $B$.

*Addendum*.  If we cannot prove $(1)$ for an arbitrary measure $\mu$
as described, maybe we can construct $\mu$ together with $X$
in order to get $(1)$.

Comment: (1) is indeed correct. By a theorem of Gitik-Shelah (found in 5II of Fremlin) the Maharam representation of the measure algebra of $\mu$ is a countable convex combination of uncountable many coin flips each. The Borel $\sigma$-algebra corresponds to countably many factors. In particular, there must be a coin flip independent of all of them.

Comment: Your argument works even without the existence of a real-valued measurable cardinal, the non-separable extension of Lebesgue measure constructed by Kakutani and Oxtoby [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969435) satisfies (1).

Comment: Do you mean $\mu\big(X \cap B\big) = \frac{1}{2}\mu\big(B\cap[0,1]\big)$ in (2)? Also, this might be a silly question, but how can we show that $\nu$ is nontrivial on Lebesgue measurable sets?

Comment: @Zhang: I'm pretty sure it's intended as written, with $\lambda$ being Lebesgue measure. However if we can take $\mu$ to be an extension of Lebesgue measure as in Michael's comment, then it would be the same either way.

Comment: @Zhang:  I think to get your desired measure, we should push forward the measure $\nu$ from $[0,1]$ to the Cantor set $C$ under a Borel isomorphism $\phi$.  The new measure $\phi_* \nu$ is then defined on all subsets of $C$ and zero on all Borel sets, so it must be nonzero on some other subset of the Cantor set, which in particular is Lebesgue measurable.  Now you can extend $\phi_* \nu$ to the rest of $\mathbb{R}$ by making it zero outside $C$.

Comment: Thanks. I do have mistaken on $\lambda$, but I am still unable to get why $\nu$ (not $\phi_* \nu$) is nontrivial. Also, the second comment of @MichaelGreinecker says (1) could be satisfied without the existence of a real-valued measurable cardinal. Does it contradict your answer if $\nu$ is indeed nontrivial?

Comment: @Zhang: For example, $\nu(X)=1/2$.

Comment: If I correctly understand @MichaelGreinecker's comment, it says that even without a real-valued measurable, there exists a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F} \supsetneq \mathcal{B}$ and a measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{F}$, such that there is a set $X \in \mathcal{F}$ satisfying (1).  But in order to produce Zhang's desired measure, we would actually need to have $\mathcal{F} = 2^{[0,1]}$ or some similar condition, and it is this which can only happen if there is a real-valued measurable cardinal.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your patience.